# Method not found: 'System.Object Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject(System.Type)'

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

Our mvc project with json.net running without any problem on every developer except the one with the new windows 8.1 system. How can we find source of the method not found problem ?

details of the exception ;

```
[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Object Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject(System.Type)'.]
  ExtensionMethods.Eval(Object o, String propertyName) in c:\Users\maxSEPHIROTH\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LogiSysMvc\LogiSysMvc\ClassLibrary\ExtensionMethods.cs:136
  ASP.<>c__DisplayClass20.<Execute>b__1(CallbackPanelSettings settings) in c:\Users\maxSEPHIROTH\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LogiSysMvc\LogiSysMvc\LogiSysMvc\Views\Genel_Personel\GridViewEditFormPartial.cshtml:430
  DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI.ExtensionsFactory.CreateExtension(Action`1 method) +137
  DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI.ExtensionsFactory.CallbackPanel(Action`1 method) +43
  ASP._Page_Views_Genel_Personel_GridViewEditFormPartial_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\maxSEPHIROTH\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LogiSysMvc\LogiSysMvc\LogiSysMvc\Views\Genel_Personel\GridViewEditFormPartial.cshtml:11
  System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +271
  System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +121
  System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +191
  System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +762
  System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +382
  System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +431
  System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
  System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +74
  System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +388
  System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +72
  System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +303
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +155
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +184
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +136
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +66
  System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
  System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +68
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
  System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
  System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
  System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
  System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +66
  System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
  System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndProcessRequest>b__9() +44
  System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3() +34
  System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Func`1 func) +69
  System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Action action) +123
  System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +133
  System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +1097
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check Newtonsoft.Json library version on that computer (also in GAC). Non-generic `ToObject` methods where introduced in November last year, so there is slight chance this causes problem.