# MissingMethodException when authenticating with OAuth after upgrading to ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, oauth

I'm trying to upgrade my ASP.NET Core app to 3.0 from 2.2. It uses OAuth to authenticate with a third party API. It works fine locally, but when I run it on my server, the following exception is generated:

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
>        An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>   System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
>   ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthTokenResponse.get_Response()'.

I'm not sure how to debug this, or what other information would be useful to provide here. Does anyone have any ideas how to figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974933/method-not-found-system-object-newtonsoft-json-linq-jtoken-toobjectsystem-typ)?

Comment: I don't think that's the same problem I'm seeing. I'm running my app in a Docker container (using the official image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0`), so I wouldn't expect there to be any old versions of assemblies that are getting loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authentication was happening in a class library, and it was still referencing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies`. version 2.2. The error I was  getting is because in .NET Core 3, `OAuthTokenResponse.Response` was changed to use `System.Text.Json` instead of Newtonsoft. I guess on my development machine, it loaded the old version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth`, while in my production environment it was loading the new version.

Unfortunately the latest version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth` isn't available as a separate package (at least at the time of this writing). In order to use it, I had to made the following changes to my class library:

- Change it to target `netcoreapp3.0` instead of `netstandard2.0`
- Remove the references to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies`
- Add a `FrameworkReference` to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`.

Once I made those changes, authentication worked in production for me again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I need to google and microsoft service account (in dot net core 3.0):

1. remove(or uninstall) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth Nuget package
2. add(or install)  OAuth2 Nuget package
3. add Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google Nuget package
4. add Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount Nuget
   package

and it is working now.